# Accessing values from dictionaries nested in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

First question here!

```
countries = [{'country': 'Italy', 'size':3,'reg':9},
             {'country': 'Germany', 'size':7,'reg':1},
             {'country': 'USA', 'size':9,'reg':4},
            ]

weights = {'size' : 100, 'reg' : 30}
```

I am trying to multiply values from the 'countries' nested dictionaries with the value associated with the matching key in the 'weights' dictionary. I tried a for loop approach as the values in 'weights' will be updated by the user.

I have tried this:

```
countries_weighted = copy.deepcopy(countries)

for key in weights.items():
        for i in countries_weighted:
           countries_weighted[i][key] *= weights[key]
```

That doesn't seem to work:

```
-
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-9753dabe7648> in <module>()
     13 for key in weights.items():
     14     for i in countries_weighted:
---> 15        countries_weighted[i][key] *= weights[key]
     16 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for i in countries_weighted:` will return the values in `countries_weighted` to your variable `i`, not the index. So in this case `i` gets an entire dictionary each time. So replacing `countries_weighted[i][key] *= weights[key]` with `i[key] *= weights[key]` should work for you. But Esteban Quiros's code below is much cleaner

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
countries = [{'country': 'Italy', 'size':3,'reg':9},
             {'country': 'Germany', 'size':7,'reg':1},
             {'country': 'USA', 'size':9,'reg':4},
            ]

weights = {'size' : 100, 'reg' : 30}

for country in countries:
    for key in weights.keys():
        country[key] *= weights[key]

print(countries)
```

Comment: Makes sense.hank you Esteban Quiros, Dan and JPP for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

1. `dict.items` cycles key-value pairs, not just keys;
2. when you iterate `countries_weighted` you should *use* `i`.

So you can amend as follows:

```
for key, value in weights.items():
    for i in countries_weighted:
        i[key] *= value
```

Answer (score 0):

Only need to write `countries_weighted[i][key] *= weights[key]` as `i[key] *= weights[key]`.